# AdMob Interstitial ads not clickable

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I successfully implemented AdMob interstitial ads into my application but the only problem is that they are not clickable.

Here is my AdMob.java class:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class Admob extends AdListener{

    private Activity ctx;

    //Admob
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private AdRequest adRequest;

    private String unitId;

    public static boolean fromAdmob = false;

    public Admob(Activity ctx, String unitId)
    {
        this.ctx    = ctx;
        this.unitId = unitId;

        try{
            this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this.ctx);
            interstitial.setAdUnitId(unitId);

            interstitial.setAdListener(this);
            adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadAd()
    {
        try{
            interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        try{
            fromAdmob = true;
            interstitial.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        fromAdmob = false;
    }

}
```

And the MainPageActivity.java file:

```
public class MainPageActivity extends Activity implements IGameListener, IEventDelegate{

    //Tags
    private static final String TAG = "bubblesMainPage";

    //Context
    public static Activity instance;

    //Media
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    //Ads
    private Admob admob;

    //TapSDK
    private Tap tap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page_activity);

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

        tr
            Tap.establish(this);
            tap = new Tap(this, "xxxx");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //Admob
        this.admob = new Admob(this, "ADMOB_ID");

        //Context
        instance = this;

        //Media
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.background_music);
        mp.setLooping(true);


      //Set activity properties
        try {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Intents & Listeners
        final Intent gamePlayActivity = new Intent(this, BubbleShooterActivity.class);
        BubbleShooterActivity.listener = this;


        //Animations
        Animation scaleUpAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.scale_up);
        findViewById(R.id.play_button).startAnimation(scaleUpAnim);

        //UI Events
        findViewById(R.id.play_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            startActivity(gamePlayActivity);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();


            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.more_games_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                tap.showMoreGamesWithViewControllerAndAppID((IEventDelegate)instance);

            }
        });

    }

    /*
    Game methods - start
     */

    @Override
    public void onGameStart() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onGameStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLevelFailed() {

        //Level failed window
        try{
            Intent i = new Intent(this, LostActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "onLevelFailed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLevelUp() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLevelUp");

        if(admob != null){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try{
                        admob.loadAd();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        Intent i = new Intent(instance, WonActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onGameEnd() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onGameEnd");
    }

    /*
    TapSDK methods - start
     */
    @Override
    public void viewDidAppear() {
        Log.i(TAG, "TapSDK: viewDidAppear");
    }

    @Override
    public void viewDidDisappear() {
        Log.i(TAG, "TapSDK: viewDidDisappear");
    }

    @Override
    public void viewConnectFail(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG, "TapSDK: viewConnectFail " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void conversion() {
        Log.i(TAG, "TapSDK: conversion");
    }

    @Override
    public void onOfferComplete(int score) {
        Log.i(TAG, "TapSDK: onOfferComplete " + score);
    }

    /*
    Activity methods start
     */

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Log.i(TAG, "onBackPressed");

        try{
            Intent exitScreen = new Intent(this, ExitActivity.class);
            startActivity(exitScreen);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "onBackPressed: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // Monitor launch times and interval from installation
        RateThisApp.onStart(this);
        // If the criteria is satisfied, "Rate this app" dialog will be shown
        RateThisApp.showRateDialogIfNeeded(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if(tap != null)
            tap.onResume();

        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        if(tap != null)
            tap.onPause();

        mp.pause();

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        mp.stop();
        mp = null;

        if(tap != null)
            tap.onDestroy();

        super.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

I couldn't figure out how to show the interstitial ad when the user levels up and presses the play button (which will lead him to the next level). The interstitial ad show up when he presses the home button which will take him to the MainActivity screen.

Can someone help me to make the ads clickable? Also, any suggestions on how to add the interstitial ad after each completed level? When someone has finished a level and presses the play button, an interstitial ad should appear and when that is closed he should be able to play the next level.

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

A number of issues:

1. Don't call `interstitial.show()` from `onAdLoaded`. Call `show()` when the user presses the play button for your next level (but only if an ad is available).
2. Get rid of `public static Activity instance;` **Never** hold a static reference to an Activity. You will just leak context everywhere.
3. Instead of calling `admob.loadAd()` from `onLevelUp()` call it as soon as you create your Activity (it takes times to load an ad from the network). NB you don't need to call it from `runOnUIThread()`
4. Call `admob.loadAd()` again after each time you show the ad to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but unfortunately I'm a Java beginner and I couldn't make it work :(